# Vue/React page transition where element carries over

Tags: reactjs, animation, vue.js, transition

I’m having the hardest time figuring out how to go about a page transition where one element leaves one view and enters the next like the animation of the book thumbnail or surfboard from the linked images below.

I mostly work in Vue, but if anyone has insight on how this is done on the development side of things I’d be very appreciative!

Booking animation design
https://dribbble.com/shots/3878921-Booking-animation-design

Surf Project
https://dribbble.com/shots/3879463-Surf-Project

Comment: Both links are broken

Comment: so what is the question basically?

Comment: @LiranC I’m not sure how to do a page transition where a thumbnail for example, when clicked routes to that elements page for example, and the thumbnail seemlessly animates into the new view.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this sections of Vue documentation.

**Overview**

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Overview

**Enter/Leave from a list**

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Entering-Leaving-Transitions

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Overdrive](https://github.com/mattrothenberg/vue-overdrive)
or then use [Velocity](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity) with [Vue JS hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks)